# View not updating after remote call

Tags: angularjs

I am having an array scope variable.

$scope.rangolis = [];

I am getting data from remote calls and pushing the data to the array.

```
Service.getRangolis(page, rowcount, type, user).then(function (results) {
    $scope.rangolis.push(results);
});
```

But, the data is not getting displayed in the view. Nothing happens.

I tried apply() and it says "**apply already in progress**".

I have also tried the below code but, it say's **"digest is already in progress"** error.

```
[].push.apply($scope.rangolis, results);
```

Comment: What does `results` looks like?

Comment: No data displays in the view although data is retrieved from the remote calls.

Comment: need more details, for example, guessing the service call is from controller, right? Can you output results into console?

Comment: Yes, the data from the service call has all data and its visible in the console as it should be.

Comment: @Purus -- Can you post a sample of what `results` is?

Comment: Even a single item of the array is too long to post here.. But I am sure that the results array has data.

Comment: Why are you not accessing `.data`? have you tried `$scope.rangolis.push(results.data);`?

Comment: Why would I need to access data which is not there?